# How to prevent race condition while working with sessions?

Tags: javascript, python, django, race-condition

I’m working on an e-commerce website with a cart and products. A product’s primary key is added to the user’s session data in a dictionary `'cart_content'`. This dictionary hold product’s primary key as key and amount of the given product as value.

I successfully reproduced a race condition bug by adding simultaneously a product twice with an amount big enough so only one of the two additions sold out the product (e.g. 3 products left and adding 3 twice). The two requests increment twice the cart but there is not enough stock (in our example 3 left but 6 in cart).

How can I prevent race condition to happen like the example given above or in a multi-user case ? Does there is for example some sort of lock system that prevent `add_to_cart()` from being executed asynchronously ?

**Edit: I switched from SQLite to PostgreSQL because I wanted to test [`select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)**.

core/models.py :

```python
class Product(models.Model):
    …
    number_in_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    @property
    def number_on_hold(self):
        result = 0
        for s in Session.objects.all():
            amount = s.get_decoded().get('cart_content', {}).get(str(self.pk))
            if amount is not None:
                result += int(amount)
        return result
    …
```

cart/views.py :

```python
def add_to_cart(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        pk = request.POST.get('pk', None)
        amount = int(request.POST.get('amount', 0))
        if pk and amount:
            p = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
            if amount > p.number_in_stock - p.number_on_hold:
                return HttpResponse('1')
            if not request.session.get('cart_content', None):
                request.session['cart_content'] = {}
            if request.session['cart_content'].get(pk, None):
                request.session['cart_content'][pk] += amount
            else:
                request.session['cart_content'][pk] = amount
            request.session.modified = True
            return HttpResponse('0')
    return HttpResponse('', status=404)
```

cart/urls.py:

```python
urlpatterns = [
    …
    path("add-to-cart", views.add_to_cart, name="cart-add-to-cart"),
    …
]
```

cart/templates/cart/html/atoms/add_to_cart.html :

```html
<div class="form-element add-to-cart-amount">
    <label for="addToCartAmount{{ product_pk }}"> {% translate "Amount" %} : </label>
    <input type="number" id="addToCartAmount{{ product_pk }}" />
</div>
<div class="form-element add-to-cart">
    <button class="btn btn-primary button-add-to-cart" data-product-pk="{{ product_pk }}" data-href="{% url 'cart-add-to-cart' %}"><span> {% translate "Add to cart" %} </span></button>
</div>
```

cart/static/cart/js/main.js:

```javascript
$(".button-add-to-cart").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let product_pk = $(this).data("productPk");
    let amount = $(this).parent().parent().find("#addToCartAmount" + product_pk).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data("href"),
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            pk: product_pk,
            amount: amount
        },
        success: function(result) {
            switch (result) {
                case '1':
                    alert(gettext('Amount exceeded'));
                    break;
                case '0':
                    alert(interpolate(gettext('Successfully added %s items to the cart.'), [amount]))
                    break;
                default:
                    alert(gettext('Unknown error'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The Javascript used to reproduce the race condition. Of course it doesn’t always work the first time. Just repeat two or three times until you get the behaviour I mentioned :

```javascript
async function test() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('button-add-to-cart')[0].click();
}

test(); test();
```

Comment: I don't see how you can prevent a race condition either in the JavaScript or the sessions.  What you need to do is use [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to lock the database until the transaction is done.

Comment: Your "number_on_hold" system will allow malicious users to make it impossible for actual customers to buy products by simply creating an infinite amount of sessions with products in carts...

Comment: @AKX Indeed, the code I mentioned raises security issues that I’m aware of and I won’t ask for answers about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit with full solution - Short answer

Use [`@transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) with `select_for_update()` and manually save the session with `save()`. You have to select all sessions and evaluate with `list()` so it will lock every sessions. This is because of a multi-user scenario. **This isn’t working for SQLite** :

```python
@transaction.atomic
def _add_to_cart_atomic(request, product_id, amount):
    p = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    list(Session.objects.select_for_update())  # Force evaluation to lock all the sessions
    if amount > p.number_in_stock - p.number_on_hold:
        return HttpResponse('1')
    if not request.session.get('cart_content', None):
        request.session['cart_content'] = {}
    if request.session['cart_content'].get(product_id, None):
        request.session['cart_content'][product_id] += amount
    else:
        request.session['cart_content'][product_id] = amount
    request.session.save()
    return HttpResponse('0')

def add_to_cart(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        pk = request.POST.get('pk', None)
        amount = int(request.POST.get('amount', 0))
        if pk and amount:
            return _add_to_cart_atomic(request, pk, amount)
    return HttpResponse('', status=404)
```

---

## Long answer

### Using `@transaction.atomic` alone

Using `@transaction.atomic` decorator seems to resolve half of the issue, even if I can’t really prove this do works 100%. This works for both SQLite and PostgreSQL.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)):

> An atomic transaction is an indivisible and irreducible series of database operations such that either all occur, or none occur. A guarantee of atomicity prevents partial database updates from occurring, because they can cause greater problems than rejecting the whole series outright.

```python
@transaction.atomic
def add_to_cart_atomic(request, pk, amount):
    p = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if amount > p.number_in_stock - p.number_on_hold:
        return HttpResponse('1')
    if not request.session.get('cart_content', None):
        request.session['cart_content'] = {}
    if request.session['cart_content'].get(pk, None):
        request.session['cart_content'][pk] += amount
    else:
        request.session['cart_content'][pk] = amount
    request.session.modified = True
    return HttpResponse('0')

def add_to_cart(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        pk = request.POST.get('pk', None)
        amount = int(request.POST.get('amount', 0))
        if pk and amount:
            return add_to_cart_atomic(request, pk, amount)
    return HttpResponse('', status=404)
```

**But it raises another problem**. When I redo my double click javascript test, sometimes, I get the "Success" alert for both of the requests, even if the server doesn’t really add twice to the cart. I think this is because the SQL query is dropped without any error raised.
And sometimes, it works as expected, the first request gets a success and the second a "Amount exceeded".

### Using a lock on the current session

This is almost [Ilya Khrustalev’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77641644/11517893). If we add a `select_for_update()` on the current session. **This does not work for SQLite**:

```python
@transaction.atomic
def _add_to_cart_atomic(request, product_id, amount):
    p = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    Session.objects.select_for_update().get(session_key = request.session.session_key)
    …
```

Then this will only lock for the current session and so our little Javascript test will pass. But what about a multi-user scenario like this ? :

```python
async def add_one_to_cart(session_key):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies={'sessionid': session_key}) as session:
        async with session.post('http://localhost:8000/cart/add-to-cart', data={'pk': 1, 'amount': 1}, cookies={'sessionid': session_key}) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main():
    result = await asyncio.gather(
        add_one_to_cart('session_key_A'),
        add_one_to_cart('session_key_B'),
        add_one_to_cart('session_key_C')
    )
    print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
['0', '0', '0']
```

Meaning every request from the three different session pass even if there is only one product left! So we have a `number_on_hold` that exceed the `number_on_stock` of `2` !

### Using a lock on all sessions

This is my "Short answer".

Comment: `transaction.atomic` only ensures that either all operations finish, or none do. It does not protect you from errors resulting from concurrent access, like in your case. As Ilya said, this is why you use `select_for_update` to lock the rows you are changing. [This excellent blog post](https://hakibenita.com/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models) explains in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

THe one of the easiest way of handling race conditions is to incorporate pessimistic locks on database level. To do so, you need to wrap the operation into the database transaction and set up a lock on the object that will be common for this kind of operations.

In your case, if you store your session in the database you can do something like that

```py
from django.db import transaction


@transaction.atomic # decorate function with transaction.atomic or use it as a context manager
def handle_add_to_cart(request, product_id, amount):
    p = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    s = Session.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=request.session.pk) # NOTE: select_for_update() here
    if amount > p.number_in_stock - p.number_on_hold:
        return HttpResponse('1')
    if not request.session.get('cart_content', None):
        request.session['cart_content'] = {}
    if request.session['cart_content'].get(pk, None):
        request.session['cart_content'][pk] += amount
    else:
        request.session['cart_content'][pk] = amount
    request.session.modified = True
    return HttpResponse('0')


def add_to_cart(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        pk = request.POST.get('pk', None)
        amount = int(request.POST.get('amount', None))
        if pk and amount:
            return handle_add_to_cart(request, pk, amount) # <-- moved logic for cleaner code
    return HttpResponse('', status=404)
```

If you have authenticated user id it would be better to use it instad of Session.

Please take into account that set a lock on global object such as Session or User may lead to decreased troughput of your backend, since requests will have to queue on after another.

Comment: Why do we have to use both `@transaction.atomic` and `select_for_update()`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all these. `select_for_update` can be executed in an a scope of transaction only.

Comment: I tested your code with small changes: (1) Use `session_key` instead of `pk` for `Session.objects.select_for_update().get()`. (2) Replace `pk` by `product_id` when accessing to `cart_content`. It seems the `select_for_update()` is useless… I have the same behaviour that I mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642381/11517893): This is half-working because of the `@transaction.atomic`

Comment: This is because I’m using SQLite, which does not support `select_for_update()`

Comment: Ah! that explains everything. I should ask about it beforehand.

Comment: SQLite3 is generally not meant to be used in an environment with concurrent writes. Its locking is lacking compared to the other database engines, and what little locking control it does have, with `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION`, is not supported by Django (still possible, through issuing explicit raw SQL). When concurrency is needed, SQLite3 can perform very well as a read-only database, but otherwise it is only really good for development, when you would be the only user to write to it. When you switch to production, it is best to use a different engine, like PostgreSQL or MySQL/MariaDB.